# JXTable - How to render column as Icon/Label?

Tags: rendering, swingx, jxtable

I have a JXTable up and running but I would like to render a column as
a label or Icon. I already have the code to convert the string value into a
label (with a series of icons appended together). I just need to know
how to tell the table to render it as such.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you might consider to explain more detailed what exactly you want to achieve (at least code snippets, better a SSCCE), then I could try to show you how that's done the SwingX'sh way :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JXTable extends JTable so it's done the same way. If anyone found this just see an example here: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/javax.swing.table/CustRend.html

Comment: actually, that's not the way you do it in SwingX rendering :-) - instead implement custom StringValue and/or IconValue and configure a DefaultTableRenderer (note: that's a SwingX renderer, not the core default) with those

Comment: There are many example: have a look at the demos webstartable on the project home and renderer related code in the test hierarchy. There are also some (cough ..) design arcticles in the wiki